# Nagios could be support on a google cloud instances?

Tags: nagios, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to install Nagios in GCP Linux instances, I have a curiosity, it will work in GCP or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can install any legitimate software in a GCP instance. Before installing any software, it is advisable to check that you are not violating any [ToS](https://cloud.google.com/terms/) of Google Cloud Platform.

In your case, you could be able to install and run 'Nagios' in a GCP instance with out any issue. But, make sure that your 'instances' have met the system requirements for the particular software as well. (For Nagios XI, the system requirements are mentioned [here](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article.php?id=12).)